# Get remaining dates of month sql server

Tags: sql-server

In the below query I get the dates of the month january on which dates did 'Tokyo Traders' got order

I want to get the dates on which 'Tokyo Traders' didn't get orders.

```
SELECT DATEPART(DAY, Orders.OrderDate) 
FROM Orders 
JOIN OrderDetails ON Orders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID 
JOIN Products ON OrderDetails.ProductID = Products.ProductID 
JOIN Suppliers ON Suppliers.SupplierID = Products.SupplierID 
WHERE Suppliers.CompanyName = 'Tokyo Traders' 
    AND DATEPART(MONTH, Orders.OrderDate) = 1 
    AND DATEPART(YEAR, Orders.OrderDate) = 1997;
```

Comment: Please give sample data and Output.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by your table names I'm assuming you don't have any table with the missing dates of January, if you don't have orders for them.

Hence, the first part of my query generates all of the dates of January 1997 so you have a full list of them.

Now, to exclude from this list the dates in which orders by `Tokyo Traders` have been made, I use a `LEFT JOIN` and exclude `NULL` results from the Orders table.

```
;WITH dates
AS (
    SELECT CAST('01-JAN-1997' AS DATE) AS sdate

    UNION ALL

    SELECT dateadd(day, 1, sdate) AS sdate
    FROM dates
    WHERE dateadd(day, 1, sdate) < CAST('01-FEB-1997' AS DATE)
    )
SELECT d.sdate                   AS [Full Day]
    , DATEPART(DAY, d.sDate)     AS [Day]
FROM dates d
    LEFT JOIN Orders o
        ON d.sDate = o.OrderDate
    LEFT JOIN OrderDetails
        ON Orders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID
    LEFT JOIN Products
        ON OrderDetails.ProductID = Products.ProductID
    LEFT JOIN Suppliers
        ON Suppliers.SupplierID = Products.SupplierID
            AND Suppliers.CompanyName = 'Tokyo Traders'
WHERE o.OrderDate IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY,sv.number-1,DATEADD(MONTH,  d.m-1,CONVERT(DATETIME,LTRIM(d.y)+'-01-01')))
        ,CASE WHEN Orders.OrderID IS NULL 'No order' ELSE 'Get Order' END 
    FROM  master.dbo.spt_values AS sv
    INNER JOIN (VALUES(1997,1)) d(y,m) ON 1=1
    LEFT JOIN Orders ON DATEPART(MONTH, Orders.OrderDate) = d.m AND DATEPART(YEAR, Orders.OrderDate) = d.y
    LEFT JOIN OrderDetails ON Orders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID 
    LEFT JOIN Products ON OrderDetails.ProductID = Products.ProductID 
    LEFT JOIN Suppliers ON Suppliers.SupplierID = Products.SupplierID  AND Suppliers.CompanyName = 'Tokyo Traders' 
    WHERE sv.type='P' AND sv.number BETWEEN 1 AND DATEPART(DAY, DATEADD(d,-1, DATEADD(MONTH,  d.m,CONVERT(DATETIME,LTRIM(d.y)+'-01-01'))))
```

The follow script use for generating day serial,you can generate multiple year and month data:

```
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY,sv.number-1,DATEADD(MONTH,  d.m-1,CONVERT(DATETIME,LTRIM(d.y)+'-01-01')))

    FROM  master.dbo.spt_values AS sv
    INNER JOIN (VALUES(1997,1)) d(y,m) ON 1=1
    WHERE sv.type='P' AND sv.number BETWEEN 1 AND DATEPART(DAY, DATEADD(d,-1, DATEADD(MONTH,  d.m,CONVERT(DATETIME,LTRIM(d.y)+'-01-01'))))
```

```
-----------------------
1997-01-01 00:00:00.000
1997-01-02 00:00:00.000
1997-01-03 00:00:00.000
1997-01-04 00:00:00.000
1997-01-05 00:00:00.000
1997-01-06 00:00:00.000
1997-01-07 00:00:00.000
1997-01-08 00:00:00.000
1997-01-09 00:00:00.000
1997-01-10 00:00:00.000
1997-01-11 00:00:00.000
1997-01-12 00:00:00.000
1997-01-13 00:00:00.000
1997-01-14 00:00:00.000
1997-01-15 00:00:00.000
1997-01-16 00:00:00.000
1997-01-17 00:00:00.000
1997-01-18 00:00:00.000
1997-01-19 00:00:00.000
1997-01-20 00:00:00.000
1997-01-21 00:00:00.000
1997-01-22 00:00:00.000
1997-01-23 00:00:00.000
1997-01-24 00:00:00.000
1997-01-25 00:00:00.000
1997-01-26 00:00:00.000
1997-01-27 00:00:00.000
1997-01-28 00:00:00.000
1997-01-29 00:00:00.000
1997-01-30 00:00:00.000
1997-01-31 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Change the StartDate as per requirement

DECLARE @StartDate DATE
SET @StartDate = '20161201'    
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,number,@StartDate ),DATEPART(DAY, Orders.OrderDate)
FROM  master..spt_values
Left Outer Join Orders ON Orders.OrderDate=DATEADD(DAY,number,@StartDate )
Where  type = 'P'
AND DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(DAY,number,@StartDate)) = 12
AND DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(DAY,number,@StartDate)) = 2016
```